# How do I modify siamese network for minor modifications of image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to do quality assurance for food items let say Pizza (Pepperoni Pizza).
The goal is to check if the food that I made closely matches with the set metric. I think Siamese network algorithm fits my need.

Suppose I have trained my model to detect Pepperoni pizza with normal toppings. But later the customer wants to do a small customization ( replace topping A with B or add a new topping C).

How can I most effectively handle this scenario? 
Now my idea is to reduce the threshold for acceptance in these type of custom cases.
Also, is Siamese network the most effective approach for this problem?
All ideas are welcome.

Comment: you could train a network that classifies image parts to pizza topping (and background) and use a sliding window approach to classify each sub part of the pizza. Afterwards you will have a list of all toppings that appear on the pizza. But it will not help to find unexpected objects on the pizza.

Comment: @Micka So, if there are 5 toppings on pizza, do I use object detection to check if they are present? So do I need two models, one for doing object detection (checking each topping one by one) and another for checking the overall aesthetics of the pizza?

Comment: I think you'll have explain what kind of things you want to assure, I'm no expert in the domain of pizza quality assurance ;) Maybe you could use AutoEncoder or CycleGAN

Comment: @Micka . Two things need to be ensured. First, if all toppings are present or not. Second, if it looks okay as a whole.

Comment: so e.g. no need to count the number of tomato slices (and their positions), it is ok to just know that there are tomato slices? I would give AutoEncoder and GAN a try. https://medium.com/vitalify-asia/gan-for-unsupervised-anomaly-detection-on-x-ray-images-6b9f678ca57d